# Ubercart & QuickBooks?

Tags: ubercart, userpoints

I have a client using Ubercart who is looking to integrate with QuickBooks. After a bit of searching, I found that Ubercart itself has some discussion of this topic which seems pretty out of date:

http://www.ubercart.org/docs/quickbooks

Then I found an existing module which does not appear to be production-ready:

[Ubercart Quickbooks Integration](http://drupal.org/project/uc_qb) module

And two commercial solutions:

http://www.webgility.com/quickbooks-integration-ubercart.php

http://deepthoughtsoftware.com/courier

Does anyone have experience with any of these solutions? The site is built on D6, and uses Ubercart with a variety of extra modules, including [Ubercart Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_ubercart) module, which allows customers to earn store credit. It will be important to bring information about the store credit, along with sales & inventory, into QuickBooks.